# C++ search in an std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, find

Say I have a vector like this:

```
vector< pair<string, pair<int, int> > > cont;
```

Now I want in the `cont` find the elem which has its `first` equal to `"ABC"`. How can I do this easily with the functors and algorithms that STL provides us with (find_if, is_equal??). **(No Boost please and no new C++.)**

**EDIT: Is it possible to do without defining a Predicate functor?**

Comment: You said it yourself: `std::find_if`. You can combine it with a lambda as well.

Comment: What a pity to be in locked out of great things like C++11 and boost :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::pair<int, int> > pair_t;

struct Predicate : public std::unary_function<pair_t, bool>
{
public:
   Predicate(const std::string& s):value(s) { }
   result_type operator () (const argument_type& pair)
   {
      return pair.first == value;
   }
private:
   std::string value;
};

std::vector<pair_t>::const_iterator pos = std::find_if(cont.begin(), cont.end(),
Predicate("ABC"));
```

or lambda, if C++11.

```
auto pos = std::find_if(cont.begin(), cont.end(),
[](const std::pair<std::string, std::pair<int, int>>& pair)
{
    return pair.first == "ABC";
});
```

really, there is one not-good way to do such thing, without struct.

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::pair<int, int> > pair_t;

namespace std {
template<>
bool operator ==<> (const pair_t& first, const pair_t& second)
{
   return first.first == second.first;
}
}

std::vector<pair_t>::const_iterator pos = std::find_if(cont.begin(), cont.end(),
std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<pair_t>(), std::make_pair("ABC", std::make_pair(1, 2))));
```

Comment: With the older standard please?

Comment: Thanks for nice solutions. Is it possible to do the same without defining a Predicate?

Comment: No without hardcoding, I guess, it is possible to do with `is_equal`, `bind2nd` and one more STL method which makes possible to access to the string of the vector element.

Comment: @Narek std::bind2nd works only with callable objects and cannot work with function (with functor created by ptr_fun too). equal_to uses operator ==, so you need overloading in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you need faster than `O(N)` search, you can replace `vector` 
with `map` (or add parallel) for `O(log N)` search (or `O(1)` with `unordered_map`), no functor is needed:

```
vector<pair<string, pair<int,int>>>  cont {{"ABC",{1,11}}, {"DFG",{2,22}}};
map        <string, pair<int,int>>   M(cont.begin(), cont.end());
cout << M["ABC"] << endl;
```

And using [RO library](http://volnitsky.com/project/ro/) (shameful plug), this will be just:

```
#include <sto/sto.h>
using namespace sto;

...
auto it = cont / (_0=="ABC");
```

Here `/` overloaded op which internally calls `find_if`;  `_0` - reference to first element of tuple (or pair) in STO lambda expression; `_0=="ABC"` - lambda expression which generates predicate for `find_if`

Comment: unordered data structures are likely to be slower than ordered data-structures, it depends, on the other hand a vector and its grant for a contiguous allocation in memory can, sometimes, be really expensive.